# Request/Response paradigm for Websocketsharp library with using Websocket.SendAsync() and OnMessage callback function

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-core, websocket-sharp

I am trying to implement request/response paradigm for Websocketsharp library exactly same it works for HttpClient's request/response async behavior. I am trying to achieve it using the async callback as given in below code. I tried to get SendAsync method's OnMessage callback event to wait until the server sends the response. I am able to get the response within the scope of the SendAsync method but as soon as we come out of SendAsync scope it clears out the value of the response.

```
string clientResponse = null;

            var response = Task.Run(() => objWSClient.SendAsync(stream, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length), (async (completed) =>
            {
                if (completed)
                {
                    clientResponse = await WSMessageSendSuccess(reqObject, callback);

                    // Websocket response is flushed to the console window, but when it leaves the scope, it doesn't hold the response out of the SendAsync() scope.
                    Console.WriteLine(clientResponse);
                }
                else
                {
                    WSMessageSendFail(reqObject);
                    clientResponse = "Failure to send Message";
                }
            })));


            while (response.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            {
                Task.Delay(10000).Wait();
            }
            response.Wait();

            // As soon as we leave scope of WebSocket.SendAsync() method, it clears the client response variable value.
            // variable name : clientResponse;, it also works same with static property/variable.
            return clientResponse;
```

Comment: You can encapsulate the API by following Microsoft's article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap

Answer (score 2):

```
static Class WSClient{


        Private Dictionary <string, Func<string, void>> DictWSReqResp = new Dictionary <string, Func<string, void>>();
        Private WebSocket objWSClient;


        public static void init(Iconfiguration config){
            //instantiate objWSClient here, set all handlers, and connect
            objWSClient.OnMessage += new EventHandler<MessageEventArgs>(e_ServerMessageReceived);
        }




        async Task<String> Request(uri, method, payload, headers){

            //it is important that this be an async function and the return be an await, because this way we 
            //guarantee that the taskCS remains in scope of this function. If this were to return the task itself
            //then the tcs will be subject to GC.

            //the three variables below will remain alive while the task is not completed
            TaskCompletionSource<string> taskCS = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
            string trackid = trackid;
            Action<string> callback;

            //the sendAsync callback should NOT be async
            objWSClient.SendAsync(stream, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length), new Action<bool>(completed) =>
            {
                if (completed)
                {
                    callback = (payload)=>{ //this will not run unless called by the e_ServerMessageReceived handler
                        taskCS.SetResult(payload);
                        DictWSReqResp.delete(trackid);
                    }
                    DictWSReqResp.Add(trackid, callback);
                }
                else
                {
                    //create well formed errorPayload
                    taskCS.SetException(errorPayload);
                }
            });



            return await taskCS.Task;


        }



        private static void e_ServerMessageReceived(payload){ //server sends {t:1 /*for responses*/, i:<trackid>, p:<response payload>}
            if(t==1)(DictWSReqResp(payload.i))(payload.p);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the ugliness. This is my solution for much the same problem as yours. The server response is a JSON object with payload.i set to the trackid. The rest is self explanatory.

Comment: There's also a bit of logic missing. My class converts a REST message to a WS payload.